# I want to set a limit for the rows only upto 5 rows which will get added from the django.models admin panel

Tags: python, django

I have a table in my models file and I want to design it such that there is a limit to only 5 rows in the table. When the limit is exceeded error has to show and input should not take.I am new to Django so if anyone had a suggestion on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a restriction on that particular model by overriding the `has_add_permission()` in the `admin.py` file. For example:

`admin.py` file:

```
# Let's say you have a model called Post
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

MAX_OBJECTS = 5

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ['field 1', 'field 2', 'etc.']
     # other class attributes can be set here as well.

     # To allow the user to be able to add only 5 objects/rows for this model (The Post Model).
     def has_add_permission(self, request):
          if self.model.objects.count() >= MAX_OBJECTS:
               return False
          return super().has_add_permission(request)
```

That's an approach you could take, but there won't be any error messages though. If there are five existing `rows` then the `add button` will not be `visible` on the Django admin site.

You can also learn more about customizing the Django admin site in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/).

Comment: Hi Brother, thanks for the respond. The issue is solved...Do you have any suggestions for me that how can I too get such ideology of any such issues cause I'm new to django...Thanks once again bro...

Comment: One more thing instead of not showing save button can u also tell me how to show an error msg like u can't add more then 5 messages.Thanks in advance..

Comment: What I'd suggest is doing a bit more research and reading the Django docs as it's very helpful. You could also set up a custom form in the admin site to through an error as you desire. You can see this link here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin.

Comment: But you may attempt what you will, and if you can't get it to work as it should, then you can always post a question and I'm sure you'll get some assistance from this wonderful community. :-)